# Why not accumulate query loss and then take derivative in MAML with Pytorch and Higher?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

when doing MAML (Model agnostic meta-learning) there are two ways to do the inner loop:

```
def inner_loop1():
    n_inner_iter = 5
    inner_opt = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-1)

    qry_losses = []
    qry_accs = []
    meta_opt.zero_grad()
    for i in range(task_num):
        with higher.innerloop_ctx(
            net, inner_opt, copy_initial_weights=False
        ) as (fnet, diffopt):
            # Optimize the likelihood of the support set by taking
            # gradient steps w.r.t. the model's parameters.
            # This adapts the model's meta-parameters to the task.
            # higher is able to automatically keep copies of
            # your network's parameters as they are being updated.
            for _ in range(n_inner_iter):
                spt_logits = fnet(x_spt[i])
                spt_loss = F.cross_entropy(spt_logits, y_spt[i])
                diffopt.step(spt_loss)

            # The final set of adapted parameters will induce some
            # final loss and accuracy on the query dataset.
            # These will be used to update the model's meta-parameters.
            qry_logits = fnet(x_qry[i])
            qry_loss = F.cross_entropy(qry_logits, y_qry[i])
            qry_losses.append(qry_loss.detach())
            qry_acc = (qry_logits.argmax(
                dim=1) == y_qry[i]).sum().item() / querysz
            qry_accs.append(qry_acc)

            # Update the model's meta-parameters to optimize the query
            # losses across all of the tasks sampled in this batch.
            # This unrolls through the gradient steps.
            qry_loss.backward()

    meta_opt.step()
    qry_losses = sum(qry_losses) / task_num
    qry_accs = 100. * sum(qry_accs) / task_num
    i = epoch + float(batch_idx) / n_train_iter
    iter_time = time.time() - start_time

def inner_loop2():
    n_inner_iter = 5
    inner_opt = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-1)

    qry_losses = []
    qry_accs = []
    meta_opt.zero_grad()
    meta_loss = 0
    for i in range(task_num):
        with higher.innerloop_ctx(
            net, inner_opt, copy_initial_weights=False
        ) as (fnet, diffopt):
            # Optimize the likelihood of the support set by taking
            # gradient steps w.r.t. the model's parameters.
            # This adapts the model's meta-parameters to the task.
            # higher is able to automatically keep copies of
            # your network's parameters as they are being updated.
            for _ in range(n_inner_iter):
                spt_logits = fnet(x_spt[i])
                spt_loss = F.cross_entropy(spt_logits, y_spt[i])
                diffopt.step(spt_loss)

            # The final set of adapted parameters will induce some
            # final loss and accuracy on the query dataset.
            # These will be used to update the model's meta-parameters.
            qry_logits = fnet(x_qry[i])
            qry_loss = F.cross_entropy(qry_logits, y_qry[i])
            qry_losses.append(qry_loss.detach())
            qry_acc = (qry_logits.argmax(
                dim=1) == y_qry[i]).sum().item() / querysz
            qry_accs.append(qry_acc)

            # Update the model's meta-parameters to optimize the query
            # losses across all of the tasks sampled in this batch.
            # This unrolls through the gradient steps.
            #qry_loss.backward()
            meta_loss += qry_loss

    meta_loss.backward()
    meta_opt.step()
    qry_accs = 100. * sum(qry_accs) / task_num
    i = epoch + float(batch_idx) / n_train_iter
    iter_time = time.time() - start_time
```

are they truly equivalent?

---

cross-posted:

- git issue: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/60

Comment: This is interesting. What resources are you reading to get into MAML?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I'm very familiar with MAML at this point. Honestly, I just read the original paper. I think I've read it a couple of times at this point! I went to the implementation of it in higher to fully understand their pseudo-code from the paper. So go for that. Paste a link if you find it. ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this topic, so that is why I asked. I don't know what "the original paper". Are you referring to Finn 2017, "Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning for Fast Adaptation of Deep Networks"?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that in second approach you'll have to keep much more stuff in memory - until you call `backward` you'll have all unrolled parameters `fnet.parameters(time=T)` (along with intermediate computation tensors) for each of `task_num` iterations as part of the graph for the aggregated `meta_loss`. If you call `backward` on every task then you only need to keep full set of unrolled parameters (and other pieces of the graph) for one task.

So to answer your question's title: because in this case the memory footprint is `task_num` times bigger.

In a nutshell what you're doing is similar to comparing `loopA(N)` and `loopB(N)` in the following code. Here `loopA` will get as much memory as it can and OOM with sufficiently large `N`, while `loopB` will use about same amount of memory for any large `N`:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
a = 0
np.random.seed(1)
v = torch.tensor(np.random.randn(1000000))
y = torch.tensor(np.random.randn(1000000))
x = torch.zeros(1000000, requires_grad=True)

def loopA(N=1000):
    a = 0
    for i in range(N):
        a += ((x * v - y)**2).sum()
    a.backward()

def loopB(N=1000):
    for i in range(N):
        a = ((x * v - y)**2).sum()
        a.backward()
```

Regarding the normalization - two approaches are equivalent (up to numerical precision maybe): if you first sum up individual losses, then divide by `task_num`, then finally call `backward` then you'll effectively compute `d((Loss_1 + ... + Loss_{task_num})/task_num) / dw` (where w is one of the weights meta-optimizer is fitting). On the other hand if you call `backward` for each loss divided by `task_num` you'll get `d(Loss_1/task_num)/dw + ... + d(Loss_{task_num}/task_num)/dw` which is the same because taking gradient operation is linear. So in both cases your meta-optimizer step will start with pretty much same gradients.

Comment: darn it I made a mistake. I meant: `meta_loss += qry_loss` and no lists. Are they now equivalent?

Comment: Yes, equivalent in meaning, but still different memory footprint.

Comment: even with the accumulator variable they don't have the same memory footprint? Why not? They seem the same since I am adding things, how is it different to automatically add things with the `.backward()` step?

Comment: just to double check, you did see the correction right?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the updated version and my answer applies to it (I kind of assumed that is what you really meant anyway). At the time you call `meta_loss.backward` the variable `meta_loss` is holding the references to all `num_tasks` tensors `qry_loss` (so that your call `backward` can actually do what it supposed to do). If you `call backward` on each `qry_loss`, then this call will accumulate additional gradients for slow-parameters you care about and when you go to next iteration previous `qry_loss` will be available for Python garbage collector.

Comment: Thus right before `meta_loss.backward` call you absolutely have to store in memory at least `num_tasks * n_inner_iter` different versions of model parameters (and more stuff for intermediate calculations).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216016/discussion-between-alexander-pivovarov-and-pinocchio).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you think he doesn't do:
```
meta_loss += qrt_loss.detach()```  
and instead he tracks them all in a list?

Comment: The fact that values are added without detaching is easy to see just by the fact that final tensor has `grad_fn`. And there is no "list" where these are tracked. The references are saved in the process of building forward graph. E.g. after each application of `+=` operation result tensor has `grad_fn` which will contain references to summation inputs. When this is unrolled it will be done operation-by-operation. Best way to visualize this would be to install `torchviz` library, creating a variable of interest which tracks gradient and call, e.g.: `torchviz.make_dot(meta_loss)` in jupyter.

Comment: also, I just realized. If we minimize the `qry_loss` directly we are forgetting to normalize stuff by the size of the batch. I think there should be a division by the batch-size so that the backward is keeping track of that in it's accumulation function. Otherwise we are going to have to play around with the step-size hyper parameters more than needed for Adam.

Comment: Sure, you can divide by the batch size there - just have to be same value as you would divide by in the case when you accumulate gradients from all sub-tasks at once. This is really logically very similar to doing example-by-example backprop instead of full batch at once, the only difference here is that examples in a batch are rather independent and might take a lot of memory.

Comment: `F.cross_entropy` by default will compute `mean` of examples (but of course won't take care of `task_num`). So it is kind of up to you whether you want to divide the result by `task_num` additionally or not. I think it makes more sense to divide by that effectively saying that `task_num` is your meta-batch size since after that increasing `task_num` will just lead to less variance in the gradients on which meta-optimizer is working.

Comment: Also updated my answer a bit adding the part about normalization.

Comment: Oh! I know the two approaches are the same. **But the original higher example code is doing neither**. So I am suggesting to do `qrt_loss = CrossEntropy(fmld(x),y) / task_num` since their code does **not** do it. I agree that there might be some numerical issue but most likely doesn't matter (unless `task_num ` is so large that makes it round to `0` by accident)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to summarize our discussion to Alex's already great answer. It usually helps me when I go through answers to read more than 1 answer.

The main thing is realizing the main functionality of Pytorch. As I understand it really is a framework for doing derivatives automatically for you. Thus, whenever you do a forward pass, Pytorch **needs to keep track of the weights and intermediate computations** to be able to compute gradients whenever the user wants. However, once the derivatives (wrt to the corresponding variables) have been take with `.backward()` usually one does not need to keep track of the intermediate computation (unless you put the `retain_graph=True` flag) so internally Pytorch somehow stops following some references (it's our guess) and then eventually python's Garbage collector cleans things up. This reduces the memory. Thus, if one calls `.backward()` **each time inside the loop** then one is potentially saving on memory. On top of that the code in the original post has on top of that a inner loop inside the other loop. Thus, the memory foot print increases even more.

Consider the simplified pseudocode:

```
def loop_good_memory():
  for outer_i in range(nb_outer_episodes):
    for inner_i in range(nb_inner_steps):
        spt_logits = fnet(x_spt[i])
        spt_loss = F.cross_entropy(spt_logits, y_spt[i])
        diffopt.step(spt_loss)
    qry_logits = fnet(x_qry[i])
    qry_loss = F.cross_entropy(qry_logits, y_qry[I])
    qry_loss.backward()
meta_opt.step()
```

this one is good in terms of memory footprint because since we are calling `.backward()`s each time it means each iteration it drops all intermediate computations which here would be even larger due to the inner loop. In total it would be `O(nb_outer_episodes * nb_inner_steps)` without the inner backward but this is just about `O(nb_outer_episodes )`.

```
def loop_bad_memory():
  for outer_i in range(nb_outer_episodes):
    for inner_i in range(nb_inner_steps):
        spt_logits = fnet(x_spt[i])
        spt_loss = F.cross_entropy(spt_logits, y_spt[i])
        diffopt.step(spt_loss)
    qry_logits = fnet(x_qry[i])
    qry_loss += F.cross_entropy(qry_logits, y_qry[I])
qry_loss.backward()
meta_opt.step()
```

this second one (imho) is easier to read but has worse memory since each loop has `O(nb_inner_steps )` since it needs to remember the intermediate computations, in particular the inner weights are part of the graph (i.e. `fnet.parameters(time=T)`). Note that I didn't write the higher context manger but it should be there of course.

Credits to Alex thanks!